# How to get data from upper level class

Tags: java

I have a `Server` and `ServerConnection` classes where a user is connected through the `Server` and then a `ServerConnection` instance is created for him and the user is maintained there.

In `Server` I have some data and I would like the `ServerConnection` instance to be able to access it.

How it's possible?

The `ServerConnection` instance is created inside the `Server` class so it's not easy to figure out how to go up one level (to `Server` class) to get data from it.

Comment: What kind of data? Maybe your class design is not optimal.

Comment: You need to add bidirectional reference. Make ServerConnection take Server as a parameter.

Comment: @cularis, in the Server class I hold a linkedlist, I would like the serverconnection get the size of it, so I created inside server class a function to get it's size but how do I access this function from serverconnection instance?

Comment: By "upper level class", do you mean to say that `ServerConnection` is an [inner class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) of `Server`?

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa, the Server class is always updated so passing the server as parameter is not relevant in my case, I think

Comment: @AlistairIsrael, Yes, inside the Server class, whenever new user is connected, a ServerConnection instance is created for him and then I do ServerConnection.run.

Comment: Note that the *source files* may be called `Server.java` and `ServerConnection.java`, but the *classes* are called `Server` and `ServerConnection`.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer, Yes I know, I just typed .java to make it clear

Comment: @Alon: think about it: **what** does it make clearer if you use the wrong name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ServerConnection` is an inner class of `Server`, you can directly access the `Server` instance's fields (even if it is shadowed):

```
public class Server {   
  private String data;

  public class ServerConnection {
     private int data; //shadows Server.data       

    public void connect() {
      //access Server.data of the Server instance associated with this instance
      Server.this.data = "xyz"; //Note that you also have write access, so that might be dangerous
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

A better approach might be to pass the `Server` instance to the `ServerConnection` and expose the data by getters:

```
public class ServerConnection {
  private Server server;

  public ServerConnection(Server s) {
    server = s;
  }

  public void connect() {
    String serverData = server.getData();
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the instance of Server to the ServerConnection when you create it. So that constructor

```
public ServerConnection(Server serverInstanceParam) {
    this.serverInstance = serverInstanceParam
```

can store the instance of the server locally. Then you can access it in all instance-methods in ServerConnection.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, I'd advice against letting the `ServerConnection` directly reference the `Server` object, since that creates a circular dependency. If it's just a simple value you want the connections to inherit, like a string or an integer, just pass it as a parameter to the `ServerConnection` constructor:

```
class ServerConnection {
    private final int timeout;
    public ServerConnection(int timeout) {
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }
}
// Usage from the Server class:
ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(timeout);
```

If it's a more complicated structure, you might want to make a separate class of it:

```
class ServerConfig {

    private int timeout;
    private boolean keepAlive;
    private String id;
    // accessors omitted

}
```

... and then pass that as a parameter to the `ServerConnection` constructor.